# How to add (multiple) files to (different) directories within an existing SVN repository (that has no local working copy)?

Tags: svn, command-line

I am writing a tool that will (among other things) automate the process of adding files to an SVN repository branch. The repository branch already exists, is potentially large (tens, or hundreds, of GB), and contains many subdirectories. My tool will need to accept several files and add those files to various (already-existing) directory points within the branch.

Essentially, I have a repository branch living at `http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository` that contains (sub-) directory trees `a/...`, `b/...`, `c/...`, `d/...` and so on.

Then I have files that I want to add to, for example:

```
http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/a/a_1/file1
http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/a/b_1/b_1_1/file2
```

(and so on).

Those files may already exist within the repository (in which case they will need to be overwritten with the local copy) or may not exist (in which case they will need to be added). The subdirectories `a/a_1` and `b/b_1/b_1_1` may be assumed to already exist (and have other files in them). I have a "decent number" (usually on the order of between 20 and 50) files to be uploaded at a time.

Said repository branch has no local working copy (and there is no enduring reason for a local copy to exist once this operation is complete).

From the searching I've already done on this process, it *seems* like the best approach is along the lines of:

- create a local working copy of the repository;
- copy my files into same;
- `svn add` the files; then
- commit the whole kit-and-kaboodle.

To wit:

```
svn checkout https://svn.example.com/path/to/repository /local/path --depth=empty
mkdir -p /local/path/a/a_1 && cp -f file1 /local/path/a/a_1/.
mkdir -p /local/path/b/b_1/b_1_1 && cp -f file2 /local/path/b/b_1/b_1_1/.
...etc...
svn add /local/path/* --depth=infinity
svn update /local/path --accept=mine-full
svn commit /local/path --message="some message"
```

...however when I try this, I get the error `Directory '/local/path/a' is out of date` (followed by `Path already exists, path '/path/to/repository/a'`).

At one point, while playing around with things, I managed to combine the above with some form of `svn resolved` which initially appeared to work, until I realized it had removed every *other* file in the repository target subdirectory. Oops!

Does anyone have a good way of addressing this? Downloading the entire repository branch (with all its files) is not feasible; as mentioned above, it is too large in size for this to be a workable solution (especially as I will not need it afterwards, so it will be immediately deleted locally).

From searching, there does not seem to be a good way to checkout the SVN branch's directory structure only, without the associated files. My best idea right now is to walk the local directory structure and address each file one-at-a-time, checking-out, adding, and committing them to the repository in a separate operation. But this involves potentially many checkins per batch, which is not ideal.

(`svn import` is likewise not ideal because of the files which may already be in the repository, and thus need to be overwritten.)

Any good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching [svnmucc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html).

You can do some works on a repository *without* working copy. For example you can create directory with `svnmucc mkdir http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/newdir`, put a file with `svnmucc put myfile http://svn.example.com/path/to/repository/any_file`, etc. Of course you can use `-m` option to define the commit message (without it you should edit a file as in `svn commit`).

You can read some examples [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.working-without-a-wc.html).

Comment: Awesome. Just glanced at the documentation and it looks super-useful. Thanks! Will try it out and if it works, I'll accept this answer!